# Add class to navigation link of page

Tags: css, navigation

On my Wordpress site I have a three level navigation. In the second level of every main navigation item is a "toolkit" page.

I would like to highlight this page in the navigation. Is there anyway that I can add a class to a page, so that I could style its navigation link separately? Is there a plugin out there that would allow me to do this?

I'm hoping it would be something like in the Page Editor screen is a custom field that allows me to input a class. The class is then generated when calling the WP_List_Pages function. Then with some simple CSS and can change the background of all those links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also simply use css: `#menu-item-ID` (where "ID" is the unique ID of the page/post/category/whatever).

Comment: This is what I had to end up doing using wp_list_pages() because the Wordpress Menu function wasn't working. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

In the menu editor open the "Screen options" tab, and check the "CSS classes" checkbox. Now you can add any class you like to each menu item

Comment: Oh. I would have to use a custom menu to achieve this?

Comment: oh, sorry, I missed that you are using WP_List_Pages. That function automatically add a class to every <li> with the ID of the page: page-item-ID.  You can use CSS selector ul li.page-item-ID a{ ... } to customize that link

Comment: also, if you define your body like: <body <?php body_class(); ?>> WP add an unique class to each page, post, category, etc